# Carbon count hours with 3 digits

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have an application that counts hours from several records. Now I detect a situation if the hours returns me more than 2 digits.

For exemple I have a `$total = '102:00:00'` with 3 digits it's returns me this errors:

```
A two digit minute could not be found
```

The error occurs when I try do this: `Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $total);`

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to create a date or a duration?

Comment: Total looks like a time length measurement, not a date. Do you expect a time length measurement or a date?

Comment: I need a timestamp from this hours @DelenaMalan

Comment: What timestamp do you expect from 102 hours?

Comment: What I need is sum 102:00:00 hours with 05:00:00 and return this value. Until now what I do is createFromFormat of each hour, sum both timestamp and createFromTimestamp with this value. maybe I'm complicating @DelenaMalan

Comment: You are confusing two different concepts, one is representing a moment in time. And the other (what you seem trying to achieve) is representing a time length.
Moment in time: Yesterday ay six, Duration: 7 hours. If you are trying to represent the later what format do you want it? Hours/seconds/minutes....? What does 05:00:00 mean?

Comment: What I want is the max hours between two different hours in Hours/Minutes/Seconds @namelivia

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not confuse a actual Date(Time) and a time interval. DateTime oriented function will not help you. Just create your own function to add two duractions. See (pseudo-)code below

```
function add_duration($h1,$m1,$s1,$h2,$m2,$s2)
{
  $s3 = ($s1 + $s2)%60;
  $m3 = ($m1 + $m2 + floor(($s1 + $s2)/60))%60;
  $h3 = $h1 + $h2 + floor(($m1 + $m2 + floor(($s1 + $s2)/60))/60);
  return [$h3,m3,s3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess:

```
$time1 = '05:00:00';
$time2 = '120:00:00';
$components1 = explode(':', $time1);
$components2 = explode(':', $time2);
$diff = ($components2[0] * 3600 + $components2[1] * 60 + $components2[2]) - ($components1[0] * 3600 + $components1[1] * 60 + $components1[2]);
$total = floor($diff / 3600) . gmdate(":i:s", $diff % 3600);
```